# Animate all cells of UICollectionView like springboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, animation

I want to add iOS spring board animation to all of my cells.I have add the below code by which i am able to animate only a single cell but i am not able to animate all of the cells.Please how will it work.

I have tried this.

**Define Variables**

```
 UIButton* _deleteButton;
 CGPoint p;
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr;
```

**Add gestures**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getUserAlbums];
    arr_userAlbums=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //afdd gesture code
    lpgr
    = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .3; // To detect after how many seconds you want shake the cells
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.collection_view addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

**Add gestures:**

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }
    p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view]; // Store (x,y) co-ordinate where the user has tapped the cell in point p.

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    }
    else
    {
        // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
        UICollectionViewCell* cell =
        [self.collection_view cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // do stuff with the cell

        CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        [anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
        [anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/43]];
        [anim setDuration:0.1];
        [anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
        [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        [cell.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"SpringboardShake"];
        //_mainImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        //[cell bringSubviewToFront:_deleteButton];

        CGFloat delButtonSize = 20;

        _deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
        _deleteButton.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        _deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [_deleteButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:_deleteButton];


        [_deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteyourItem) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"longPressed"];
    }
}
```

**Method to delete items**

```
-(void)deleteyourItem
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    //delete your item based on the `indexpath` from your collectionViewArray here.
    //OR If you are accessing the database to display the collectionView, you can compare the value fetched based on the `indexPath`, with your database value and then delete it.

    // Reload your collectionView after deletion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

Put all this animation code into a method in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. Let's say the method is named `- (void)shakeItem:(BOOL)shake`.

On `handleLongPress` you should iterate on `collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems`, on these cells you should call method `shakeItem:`.

Keep in mind, you need to override `prepareForReuse` method and cancel the shaking effect there. You also need to save that the items are shaking and begin shaking new dequeued cells.

Another way is to follow any tutorial (there are quite a lot of them): http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-springboard-like-layout-with-the-uicollectionview-class--mobile-13426 but it won't use your code ;)

Comment: Tutplus tutorial is very hard to learn & as well i have to re write the all code.what is that **collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems** method

Comment: @TechGuy Because you'd have to rewrite all the code I suggested the "easy" implementation (not the most efficient & beautiful, as for that you'd use animation replicator). As to your question: `UICollectionView` has methods `indexPathsForVisibleItems` and `visibleCells` - it will return you indexes / cells which are currently visible. You need to shake only visible items ;). BTW it's good to see the documentation of the method (alt+click).

Comment: okay so you say i need to call the method indexPathForVisible items.But how can i call it so that it should animate the all cells?Also what if scroll up do then will it also animate the new cells which are visible?

Comment: @TechGuy As the name of the method suggest, it is not designed to animate anything but to get the list of visible cells. It's your code business to perform the animation on them. You just iterate through the cells and call the method on each of them like you did in your code. To the second question read my answer carefully: _You also need to save that the items are shaking and begin shaking new dequeued cells._.